# Router render same component for every rout path

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

For both path react render only landing component.
for path '/' and for path '/home' also. router render only landing component.

```
import {Route, BrowserRouter, Switch, HashRouter} from  'react-router-dom'
import Layout from './pages/Layout'
import './style/style.css';
import Landing from './pages/Landing';

function App() {
  return (
    
    <>

    <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route  path='/'><Layout/></Route>
        </Switch>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/land"><Landing/></Route>
        </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
    </>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the reason is that you use 2 `Switch` components, use one instead